# How to fix on this code the Error 13 (types mismatch)?

Tags: excel, vba

Actually I need to implement a color change in some Combobox (UserForm). I created a class and all needed code, but in the line "For Each cbbox In F01_MAIN_FORM.Controls" I have the error 13.

Class module code(named "Colors")

```
Option Explicit
Public WithEvents combo As MSForms.ComboBox

Public Sub Color_Changer()
    Select Case combo.Value
        Case "Sí"
            combo.BackColor = RGB(0, 255, 0)
        Case "No"
            combo.BackColor = RGB(255, 0, 0)
        Case "En curso"
            combo.BackColor = RGB(255, 80, 0)
        Case "No Aplica"
            combo.BackColor = RGB(100, 100, 100)
End Sub
```

UserForm code (named "F01_MAIN_FORM")

```
Option Explicit
Dim Box_Collection As New Collection

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

Dim cbbox As MSForms.ComboBox
Dim color_box As Colors

For Each cbbox In F01_MAIN_FORM.Controls
    Set color_box = New Colors
    Set color_box.combo = cbbox
    Box_Collection.Add color_box
Next cbbox

End Sub
```

Normally this code needs to change the color when I want.
I need to perform the code also to detect when a combobox changes, and change their color automatically.

Actually the code shows

> error 13

when I try to read the line

```
For Each cbbox In F01_MAIN_FORM.Controls
```

Comment: You're missing an `End Select` in your `Color_Changer()`

Comment: I believe `cbbox as Control` would be appropriate, then you have to check if the control is a combobox without your loop.  This will let you touch all types of controls and only action those which are appropriate to your needs

Comment: `F01_MAIN_FORM.Controls` contains probably other controls than Comboboxes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expanding on my comment below question:

---

You need to determine the `TypeName(cbbox) = "ComboBox"` within your loop, where `dim cbbox as control`.

```
Dim cbbox as control

for each cbbox in F01_MAIN_FORM.Controls
    If TypeName(cbbox) = "ComboBox" Then
        Set color_box = New Colors
        Set color_box.combo = cbbox
        Box_Collection.Add color_box
    End if
next cbbox
```

You are touching *all* controls in the userform when you loop through `.Controls` and if you touch one that isn't a combobox, you'll get a mismatch.  This is why you dimension `as control` then determine the `typename()` for each control found.